# Webpack: limit output line length

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

Is there a way to limit the line length of the output file from webpack?

I'm building a javascript file for an environment with a 255 character line length limit, and the generated file has a line that is longer than that. This is part of webpack's bootstrap code, it's not from the input file.

I've looked at uglify-loader, but it does not seem to be updated to support webpack >= 2.

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that does not involve minifying the output, only splitting the lines that are too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though uglify-loader seems abandoned, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin did the trick.

The following config minifies the output, but at least the 255-character limit is respected.

```
plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      compress: true,
      output: {
        max_line_len: 255,
      },
    }),
]
```